# mediaStreamSource doesn't work, using an audio object with the media stream doesn't loop it through mediaElementSource

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

I am receiving a stream through the RTCPeerConnection, but can't get it to work properly. Using the mediaStreamSource doesn't work (I read that there was a bug in chrome?). So I tried a workaround: using `webkitURL.createObjectURL` to put the stream in an audio object. This works, but not with 'mediaElementSource'. When I first create the mediaElementSource and then put a dataURL of a local file in the audio element's stream, it works like normal, but whenever I add the stream to the element, it starts playing normal (like when `mediaElementSource` has not been made, as if it is just a normal audio element without the AudioContext. When I then put another dataURL from a local file in the element, it directly plays through the AudioContext. Does anyone have any idea?

Edit: found the [chrome issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=241543).

<strike>Guess I will use canary then.</strike> Other solutions are welcome :)
edit2: sadly that doesn't work...